# GCP Load Balancer or Kubernetes type = LoadBalancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When working with Google Container Engine - would people recommend GCP's native load balancer or the Kubernetes Service type = LoadBalancer option?

Which do people recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the service resource manifest, if you set the [`Type` to `LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer), Kubernetes on GKE (Google Container Engine) will automatically set up TCP load balancing (L4 Load balancer) using GCE. You will have to terminate connections in your pod using your own custom server or something like `nginx`/`apache`.

If your goal is to set up a L7 load balancer (HTTP/HTTPS), it will be better to make use of the [`Ingress` resource in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) (starting with `v1.1`). GKE will automatically set up a GCE HTTP/HTTPS L7 load balancing for this setup. This setup has the following advantages:

1. Specify services per URL path and port (it uses [`URL Maps`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/url-map) from GCE to configure this).
2. Set up and terminate SSL/TLS on the GCE load balancer (it uses [`Target proxies`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/target-proxies) from GCE to configure this).
3. GKE will automatically also configure the GCE [`health checks`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks) for your services.

More info available on the [GKE page about setting up HTTP load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer).

Remember that GKE will automatically use the available GCE load balancer support for both the use cases described above and you will not need to manually set up [GCE load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Service type to `LoadBalancer` on Google Container Engine will configure a GCP Load Balancer for you. See [Creating an External Load Balancer](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/load-balancer/) and [Services: Type LoadBalancer](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-loadbalancer).

Comment: Oh nice so it actually makes a standard GCP Load Balancer out the box - more I use GCP more I love it....

Comment: As mentioned above, this is an L4 (TCP) balancer, not an L7 one.  If your API is http or https you will want an L7 one.